# How to get match substring key in dictionary and return corresponding values on Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

New to python and lots to learn! I'm trying to return dictionary (plantdict) values with substring key input by users. Below is my code so far.

```
 def search_plant_name():
    while True:
        enter_plant_name = input('Please enter plant name: ').capitalize()
        filtered_dict_key = [key for (key, val) in plantdict.items() if enter_plant_name in key]
        filtered_dict_time = [val[0] for (key, val) in plantdict.items() if enter_plant_name in key]
        filtered_dict_info = [val[1:] for (key, val) in plantdict.items() if enter_plant_name in key]
        if ##NOT SURE WHAT TO WRITE HERE## in plantdict.items():
            print('Plant name:', str(filtered_dict_key).strip("[]").replace("'",""))
            print('Date and time of entry/revision of plant record:', str(filtered_dict_time).strip("[]").replace("'",""))
            print('Information of plant:')
            print('Date and time of entry/revision of plant record:', str(filtered_dict_info).strip("[]").replace("'",""))
        else:
            provide_option_2 = user_input_options('The plant does not exist, would you like to add in the record? (Y / N): ')
            if provide_option_2 in ('Y'):
                print('OPTION2')
                ##CREATE FUNCTION FOR OPTION 2##
```

The idea is that e.g. if user keyed in "roses" and my dictionary has "Red Roses" as a key, it will return the corresponding values of this key. But if the user keyed in a word/phrase that does not match any of my keys, s/he be given an option to add plant details to the dictionary, hence Option 2

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what could be missing. Any help will be grately appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: try to break down your function to see where it isn't working ... you could provide some data and give us a reproducible example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: What happens if the user answer "poplar" and there are records for the "Black Poplar",  the "Gray Poplar",  the "White Poplar"?

Comment: The updated question doesn't answer my question: what happens if there are ***multiple*** matches?

Answer (score 0):

filtered_dict_key is a list, not a string. .strip() isn't an operation that works on a list, only strings. The brackets: '[]' aren't string characters - they have separate meaning to python.

Your while loop will also run forever, but I assume that's not the issue at hand.

Instead of writing list comprehensions, ('[i for i in l if i == v]'), simply write your own for loop. A list comprehension will loop anyhow.

```
def search_plant_name():
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        enter_plant_name = input('Please enter plant name: ').capitalize()
        for key, val in plantdict.items():
            if enter_plant_name in key:
                print("Plant name: " + key)
                print("Date and time of entry/revision of plant record: " + val[0])
                print('Information of plant:')
                print('Date and time of entry/revision of plant record: ' + val[1])
                keep_going = False  # or put this wherever you want to exit while loop
            else:
                provide_option_2 = user_input_options('The plant does not exist, would you like to add in the record? (Y / N): ')
                if provide_option_2 in ('Y'):
                    print('OPTION2')
                    ##CREATE FUNCTION FOR OPTION 2##
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! this doesn't quite work for my substring key..

Comment: Can you share a sample of what your dict looks like? Are your keys strings? This is a very rudimentary way of doing a search - the exact substring has to match, including capitalization. If you want to ignore the capitalization, you'll want to convert both the key and the input to either all uppercase or all lowercase, using .upper() or .lower(). Using .capitalize() will change the first character to upper, and the rest to lower. It would be far more clear what you need if we could see the data we're operating on.

Answer (score 0):

Imho a dictionary is more convenient than a list, because you can have your matching records as they are stored in your little database

```
matches = {k:plantdict[k] for k in plantdict if plant_name in k}
```

If you have no matches your `matches` dictionary will be empty, so if you loop over its `items` you will do nothing if you have no matches (please edit the format string according to your preferences)

```
for k, v in matches.items():
    print("""\
Name: $s
Time: %s
Info: %s"""%(k, v[0], v1[]))
```

At the end you can ckeck if `matches` is empty and prompt the user accordingly

```
if matches == {}:
    if input('...')[0].upper() == 'Y':
        ...
```

---

PS I have to say that the design of your function, that never returns, does not appear well thought out…

---

PS2 I deliberately avoided ① to use the same variable names as you did and ② to provide executable code.